# Searching validityState for values

Tags: javascript, validation

I may be approaching this the wrong way, but I'm confused how to extract information from an `input`'s `validityState` object.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#myinput');
var validity = input.validity;
var keys = Object.keys(validity);

console.log( validity );          // [ object validityState ]
console.log( validity.valid );    // false (this is expected)

console.log( keys )               // empty array
console.log( keys.length )        // 0
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput" required>
```

My main question is, how do I find out which property is "failing" if I can't iterate over the `validityState` object?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not use `Object.keys()`.
You can simply iterate on your validity state like this:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#myinput');
var validity = input.validity;
for(var key in validity){
     console.log(key + ": " + validity[key]);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput" required>
```

**Edit:**

- `Object.keys()` only referring to keys that are in the current *Object* and does not look in the *prototype* of this *Object*. Note that `object.hasOwnProperty()` does the same test
- `in` return `true` if the property is present in the current *Object* **OR** if the property is present in the *prototype*

Comment: Should `hasOwnProperty` not also be used? I still can't understand why I can't use `Object.keys()`...

Comment: @evolutionxbox hasOwnProperty is only referring to the property of the current `Object` and not what is in his `prototype`. `in` return `true` if the property is accessible in the Object OR in the prototype (i edited my post)